# Borrar elementos de una lista HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

En el documento `HTML` hay una lista, tengo que crear una lista nueva con sus 5 primeros elementos de la lista original y después borrar dichos elementos, de la lista original. Para borrarlo, recorro las dos listas y compruebo si el contenido del `<li>` coincide, y si coincide, el elemento es eliminado de la lista original, pero con el método `remove()` no borra.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var comunidades = [];
    var listaNueva = $("<ul id='lista-nueva'></ul>");
    var listaOriginal = $("ul#lista-original li");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        comunidades.push("<li>" + $("ul li").eq(i).text() + "</li>");
    }
    $("body").append(listaNueva.append(comunidades.join("")));

    for (i = 0; i < listaOriginal.legth; i++) {
        if (listaOriginal.eq(i).text() == listaNueva.eq(i).text()) {
            listaOriginal.eq(i).remove();
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista-original">
        <li><span>Andalucía</span></li>
        <li><span>Aragón</span></li>
        <li><span>Asturias</span></li>
        <li><span>Canarias</span></li>
        <li><span>Cantabria</span></li>
        <li><span>Castilla y León</span></li>
        <li><span>Castilla La Mancha</span></li>
        <li><span>Cataluña</span></li>
        <li><span>Ceuta</span></li>
        <li><span>Comunidad de Madrid</span></li>
        <li><span>Comunidad Valenciana</span></li>
        <li><span>Extremadura</span></li>
        <li><span>Galicia</span></li>
        <li><span>Islas Baleares</span></li>
        <li><span>La Rioja</span></li>
        <li><span>Melilla</span></li>
        <li><span>Navarra</span></li>
        <li><span>País Vasco</span></li>
        <li><span>Región de Murcia</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dos problemas grandes a destacar:

1- En la línea 11 del código JS pusiste **legth** en vez de **length**, por lo que nunca va a entrar a ese ciclo for.

2- La comparación dentro del mismo for también va a fallar, porque listaNueva en este caso no es un array, sino un string, lo que debes hacer es tomar la nueva lista que ya fue graficada (renderizada) e iterar a partir de ella. El código quedaría más o menos así:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                var comunidades = [];
                var listaNueva = $("<ul id='lista-nueva'></ul>");
                var listaOriginal = $("ul#lista-original li");
    
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    comunidades.push("<li>" + $("ul li").eq(i).text() + "</li>");
                }
                $("body").append(listaNueva.append(comunidades));
                
                var listaNuevaGraficada = $("ul#lista-nueva li");
                for (i = 0; i < listaNuevaGraficada.length; i++) {
                    if (listaOriginal.eq(i).text() === listaNuevaGraficada.eq(i).text()) {
                        listaOriginal.eq(i).remove();
                    }
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="lista-original">
            <li><span>Andalucía</span></li>
            <li><span>Aragón</span></li>
            <li><span>Asturias</span></li>
            <li><span>Canarias</span></li>
            <li><span>Cantabria</span></li>
            <li><span>Castilla y León</span></li>
            <li><span>Castilla La Mancha</span></li>
            <li><span>Cataluña</span></li>
            <li><span>Ceuta</span></li>
            <li><span>Comunidad de Madrid</span></li>
            <li><span>Comunidad Valenciana</span></li>
            <li><span>Extremadura</span></li>
            <li><span>Galicia</span></li>
            <li><span>Islas Baleares</span></li>
            <li><span>La Rioja</span></li>
            <li><span>Melilla</span></li>
            <li><span>Navarra</span></li>
            <li><span>País Vasco</span></li>
            <li><span>Región de Murcia</span></li>
        </ul>
```

Con esto ya estarías comparando dos arrays y se hará la eliminación efectiva de los campos duplicados. Para efectos de pruebas siempre es bueno utilizar ***console.log()*** en diferentes puntos del código para cerciorarse de cómo va cambiando la información.

Espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

he modificado un poco tu codigo del bucle para eliminar las entradas añadidas a la lista nueva utilizando un `indexOf`para buscar coincidencias, tu codigo quedaria asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var comunidades = [];
    var listaNueva = $("<ul id='lista-nueva'></ul>");
    var listaOriginal = $("ul#lista-original li");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        comunidades.push("<li>" + $("ul li").eq(i).text() + "</li>");
    }
    $("body").append(listaNueva.append(comunidades.join("")));

    for (i = 0; i < listaOriginal.length; i++) {
        if ( listaNueva[0].innerText.indexOf(listaOriginal.eq(i).text())>-1) {
            listaOriginal.eq(i).remove();
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista-original">
        <li><span>Andalucía</span></li>
        <li><span>Aragón</span></li>
        <li><span>Asturias</span></li>
        <li><span>Canarias</span></li>
        <li><span>Cantabria</span></li>
        <li><span>Castilla y León</span></li>
        <li><span>Castilla La Mancha</span></li>
        <li><span>Cataluña</span></li>
        <li><span>Ceuta</span></li>
        <li><span>Comunidad de Madrid</span></li>
        <li><span>Comunidad Valenciana</span></li>
        <li><span>Extremadura</span></li>
        <li><span>Galicia</span></li>
        <li><span>Islas Baleares</span></li>
        <li><span>La Rioja</span></li>
        <li><span>Melilla</span></li>
        <li><span>Navarra</span></li>
        <li><span>País Vasco</span></li>
        <li><span>Región de Murcia</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.